# Swift Boolean value <invalid>

Tags: swift, boolean-operations

The attached screen shot says it all: I have a valid true Bool, I negate it with the bang operator, and (Xcode tells me) I have an invalid value.

It appears that this "invalid" value does behave as if it were false. But really, wtf?

[image]

Comment: The memory for that bool either was never initialized, or has been corrupted in some way. The only valid values for `Bool` are `0x01`  (`true`) and `0x00` (`false`)

Comment: The Xcode debug window shows clearly that the bool was initialized. That's what  line 72 does. Moreover, the `enabled` value can't be optimized out since it is used on line 73. However, this could just be an Xcode debugger bug...

Comment: I suspect this code has been edited since the debugging session was started, and that the code doesn't reflect the state of the program

Comment: On a side note, this is could be so much more simply written as `adFreeButton.isEnabled = !PurchaseState.isAdfree`

Comment: The code was not edited since the debugging session was started. And yes, I did originally have the code as you suggested. I rewrote it in this way so that you could see clearly that !true did not equal false. I've been writing code now for 40 years; I do understand booleans.

Comment: Easy there, no need to get defensive lol

Comment: This is really strange behaviour. Could you try to write a [minimal, complete, and verfiable example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why couldn't `enabled` be optimized away even if it's used? Can't it just get replaced, depending on the optimization level?

Comment: Andreas' comment could be the answer. FWIW the most minimal example, i.e. in a Playground, does not exhibit the behavior. I will see about trying to create an example, but as per Andreas, this might be very context-sensitive.

Comment: I'll just put it in an answer then

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue in Xcode 8.3.1 and Swift 3.1 https://github.com/onmyway133/notes/issues/278

I tried

- Clean build folder and delete derived data folder
- Delete the app
- Reset simulator
- Restart Xcode
- Restart Mac

But does not work. The workaround is to

```
let enabled = disable ? false : true
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no LLVM expert but I wouldn't be surprised about this behavior at all, unless optimization is set to `Onone` in which case it should have left your code alone. The intermediate variable is just asking to be optimized away, after all.

Comment: However (and i should have specified this) both enabled and disabled are used several times later in the method. (This is part of why I have *both* enabled and disabled defined: the code reads better and it is harder to inadvertently omit a bang negation symbol.) In fact, the debugger is paused at precisely one of the places where the (apparently bogus) value is being used. Finally, in debug mode, my optimize setting *is* -Onone.

Comment: I also declare variables liberally, but no matter how much I use them I still expect them to disappear and get replaced by something much better. If your screenshot is in fact from a debug run, which you are implying, then I'm afraid you'll have to wait for someone more knowledgeable.

Comment: I agree that the compiler is free to rearrange local variables if provably correct. (I'm a compiler writer. You'll sympathize with the number of times I have had to explain to students that "No, fewer locals does not mean more efficient code.") But yes the screenshot is of the Xcode debugger. Could be a harmless bug in the Swift runtime. Harmless because 0xfe (aka -2) was indeed handled as false by the control flow.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what I mean by debug run — it's not a question of whether the screenshot is of the debugger, but rather which build configuration is used when running from Xcode. `debug` config (with `Onone`) is default, but not necessary.

Comment: I see. It was the debug config with -Onone.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue,  with correct value for add code like `print(theBoolValue)`.

But when use `p` in swift command line. Or just check the value in debug stack, the value become `<invalid>(Oxfe)`.